# How can I put a file with several audio into MPEG-TS?

Tags: video, vlc, mpeg2-ts, transport-stream

I have, for example, source media file with video and several audio streams. I need to put it into MPEG-TS. In case, if I have only one video and only one audio in the source file, I can use command like:

`vlc <source_file> --sout='#transcode{vcodec=mp4v,acodec=mpga,vb=4000,ab=128,deinterlace}:standard{access=file, mux=ts{pid-video=1000, pid-audio=1001}, dst=<output.ts>}`

Could anyone explain how can I do the same for a source file with several audio tracks?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `--sout-all` to enable the streaming of all elementary streams. It is disabled by default. However I'm not aware of a method to map each stream to a custom PID.

Comment: Yes, I know about `--sout-all`. Thank you. It seems that I cannot avoid ffmpeg using.